# I can't upload my background-image from my FTP to my website

Tags: html, css, ftp

I am stuck trying to set a background-image for the header on my website. Nothing loads.
My hosting has disabled linking images via an external URL, so I've put the image on Filezilla, that also doesn't work.

I have copied the image path from the FTP and pasted that in my html file which didn't work. I have also tried to copy code I found in tutorials, didn't work. 
Whether it's the code or the FTP, I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you paste the code that are trying to use ?

Comment: can you paste the code or your site url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you make a map in your FTP account, we name this map *Test* for now.
You open the map *Test* and you upload a file *index.html*. You also upload an image in the map *Test*. So you have a map named *Test*, in the map 2 files, one *index.html* and *image.jpg*.

When you want to use this image in your *index.html* file you just write the simple code `<img src="image.jpg"/>`. This should upload the image. You visit by the link: www.yourhosting/ftpname/Test/index.html

EDIT:

**NOTE:** You should work online, not on your local host. As I can see youre already doing this by uploading on FileZilla.